# Can we have discussions?

Tags: discussion, questions, subjective

Guys, I just wonder if people are allowed to have civilized discussion (on any IT topic) on this forum without actually being accused of starting a row. I'm asking this question for a reason that few days I've asked few questions referring to VM, JIT etc. and compared them to C++ way and despite the fact that I've explained myself that I'm not starting any agro with anyone, that I'm really just genuinely curious, my post was first closed and then removed. I'm asking: What's wrong with asking nonstandard questions which sometimes my be quite difficult to answer?
Thanks

Comment: Definitions required for: *raw, agro, nonstandard*.

Comment: Did you mark those as "community wiki"?

Comment: @Aaronaught: 'raw' was mispelling of 'row', 'agro' means trouble, and nonstandard means something that isn't standard, like your level of pedantry and inability to use the interwebs to look up words yet still be able to post here.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, but can you please also change "reffering" to "referring" (I would if I could...) BTW, what's wrong with "nonstandard" - at least it's in the dictionary?

Comment: @Jeff I think Aaronaught was asking for links pointing to concrete examples of what the OP complains about, which is a fair thing to do.

Comment: @Aaronaught:  "agro" is from certain video games (particularly MMORPGs).  If you get too close to a monster, you attract its attention and it attacks you.  You did that by getting in "agro" range.  "I'm not starting any agro with anyone" means "I'm not initiating combat".

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I feel a lot smarter and more well-adjusted now, and promise that I will learn to better utilise teh intarwebz in teh futuarz.  Here is something else I found on the intertube: http://www.sarcasmdetector.com/product.html

Comment: @Aaronaught - I ought to report your comment for SPAM! http://www.amazon.com/SPAM-Classic-12-Ounce-Cans-Pack/dp/B001EQ5NHE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=grocery&qid=1270515066&sr=8-1

Comment: @Aaronaught - Also, for only $100/hour I can look up definitions of those 3 words for you!

Comment: @aaronaught: No one missed the sarcasm. Just thought it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's wrong with asking nonstandard questions which sometimes my be quite difficult to answer?

Absolutely nothing, but SO/SF/SU are *Q & A* sites. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> What kind of questions should I not
>   ask here?
>
> Avoid asking questions that are
>   subjective, argumentative, or require
>   extended discussion. This is not a
>   discussion board, this is a place for
>   questions that can be answered!

so while questions often *grow* into extended discussions, questions that are designed to spark discussion from the start are often closed as "subjective and argumentative".

That is sad sometimes, as there are few places as great as SO to reach a huge programming audience, but on the other hand, it helps keep the question base "clean" with concrete questions and answers, and thus, useful for a large audience on the long term.

Comment: Fair play. %100