# I hate having to hit 'space' twice to insert a new paragraph in my post. I'd rather hit enter

Tags: feature-request, markdown, linebreak

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should the markdown renderer treat a single line break as <br>?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br)
>   [Why you should press Return key 2 times to insert a new line?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line)

Is doing something the longer way instead of shorter while breaking common habits and conventions in order to achieve this same effect better? If you think not (as most people) why do I have to, in order to have new line press space space enter instead of just enter? If as I've discussed it few times on MSO you have to use meta why can't someone code it that pressing enter would insert two spaces before it? It's so freaking frustrating and unnatural. Why, God why?! It's so freaking unnatural and frustrating...

Comment: It took awhile for me to figure out what you were talking about.

Comment: ...I never actually knew you could do that to insert a single line break. You learn something new every day.

Comment: I have written a (quite lengthy) [explanation of this behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635).

Answer (score 3):

I don't find it as life-ruining as Robert, but this always did seem unnecessary. Why doesn't markdown just treat line breaks as line breaks; is there some syntactic reason it ignores them?

Comment: It ignores them to make one use a blank line, which helps in non-HTML rendering (including looking at the Markdown source text itself).

Answer (score 0):

OP Question Translated:

> I hate having to hit 'space' twice to insert a new paragraph in my post. I'd rather hit enter.

Answer:

[This has been discussed on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/).

Comment: Discussed, but apparently no conclusion was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Using two spaces does *not* start a new paragraph. When doing that, you're breaking the layout. You should use a blank line instead, and only use the two spaces when you really need a new line *without* starting a new paragraph.

And above all: note that the posts are not only used on the websites. Though on the website using the two spaces might only have some bad effect on the layout, for other usage scenarios you might break even more.

Comment: I think the OP is more concerned about the linebreak functionality, not specifically for making new paragraphs. The word "paragraph" is only resultant from George's translation.

Comment: @ccornet, but the OP shouldn't use line breaks, unless *really* needed.

Comment: I don't disagree that line breaks are only an "as necessary" implement, paragraphs are much nicer. But I don't think that the OP necessarily is abusing them at all.

Comment: @ccornet, I'm [afraid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844446/shall-i-optimize-or-let-compiler-to-do-that) [he](http://superuser.com/questions/136295/sort-results-in-google-closed) [does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45569/can-we-have-discussions). (But not always.)

Comment: Point taken.